Convinent way of making SystemCallFilter lists
Systemd unit hardening is pretty new to me, for SystemCallFilter in specific, I had to deal with it once in my distro because one of the units was crashing, and I had no idea why, but that is about it.
I once again saw them when reading this blog, and it mentioned using strace to figure out what syscall "groups" had to be added to the filter in order for an application to work correctly. But using strace directly seems rather cumbersome, is there some canonical way to accumulate the syscalls?
After some googling, I wrote this small bash script that seems to do just that, although I am not sure if this is really the ideal way to do this.
declare -A syscalls

# Make a YAML file from the list of syscall groups
syscallList=$(awk -f- <(systemd-analyze syscall-filter) <<'EOF'
/^@/{print "\"" $1 "\":"}

/^ {4}[^#]/{
    gsub(/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]/, "");
    gsub(/@.*/, "\""$1"\"");
    print "   - " $1
}
EOF
)

# Search through the YAML string for groups that contain the needed syscall, and 
# add it to the associate array (acting as a python set)
while read -r syscall
do
  syscalls["$(yq ".[] | select(.[] == \"$syscall\") | key" <<< "$syscallList" | head -n 1)"]=
done <<< "$(strace -c "$@" 2>&1 1> /dev/null | awk 'NR > 2 {print $NF}' | head -n-2)"

echo "${!syscalls[@]}"

There is also another version that uses a PID instead, so strace -c -p $1.
